# Find $P(X=k)$ where $X$ is the random variable that represents the number of draws required to obtain a white ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

Consider a box containing one black ball and one white ball. Every time a black ball is drawn, a die is rolled and a number of black balls equal to the result of the die are added to the box. We want to determine $P(X=k)$  where $X$ is the random variable that represents the number of draws required to obtain a white ball.

---

Examples I found:
$$\begin{split}
P(X=1)&=\frac 12\\
P(X=2)&=\frac 1{24}\\
P(X=3)&=\dfrac 1{2.6^2}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^6\dfrac {k+1}{k+2}\sum_{i=1}^{6}\dfrac 1{i+k+1}= 0.0472490588115\dots$
\end{split}$$

it appears that there is no elegant formula for $P(X=k)$.

Comment: This is not clear. How is $Y$ measured?  You say it refers to the number shown on the die, but the die is rolled many times, so which toss do you record?  I note that you never refer to $Y$ after defining it, so many you just meant to leave it off?

Comment: I need Y to apply the theorem of total probabilities. see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Note:  the OP is asking for the computation of the probability of ending on a specified round.  I expect that's hard to get, and here I just consider the expected value.  Too long for a comment.

Consider the simpler problem for which you just add a single black ball each time you draw a black.  Thus, at the $n^{th}$ round, there would be $n$ black balls and a single white one.  This is the classical case of [Polya Urns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_urn_model).

In that case, the probability of a win on round $k$ would have probability $\frac 1{k+1}$ so the odds of failing for $n-1$ consecutive rounds would be $$\frac 12\times \frac 23\times \frac 34\times \cdots \times \frac {n-1}{n}=\frac 1n$$

It follows that the probability of drawing the white ball for the first time on the $n^{th}$ turn is $$\frac 1n\times \frac 1{n+1}$$

Thus the expected number of rounds you need in order to get that white ball is given by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\times \frac 1n\times \frac 1{n+1}=\infty$$.

As the expected number is infinite for this game, it is clearly infinite for yours.

Comment: I know how to handle the simple case you mentioned. But that doesn't help me with my problem. I want to calculate only P(X=k) not E(X)

Comment: I would not expect there to be a sensible closed formula for that.  I would write it out for the first few values and look for patterns, maybe comparing it to what you'd get if you got the expected roll each time (never mind that it isn't an integer).  But maybe this is linear in a way I don't immediately see.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could explain to me how to calculate P(X=3)

Comment: I'd use a computer and just enumerate the cases.  There aren't very many, after all.  Again, I wouldn't expect the computation itself to shed much light, but maybe the answer can be compared to the constant $3.5$ case.

Comment: Do you at least agree with my calculation of P(X=2)? and thank you for your support

Comment: I find your formula a bit hard to read.  But I think you wrote $\frac12\times \frac 16 \times \sum_{i=1}^6 \frac 1{i+2}=\frac {341}{3360}$ and I agree with that value.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wrote a quick code to do $k=3$ and got $0.047249059$ which seems sensible enough, but I strongly recommend checking it.  I didn't debug it at all.

Comment: And, unsurprisingly, these answers don't match those obtained by constantly adding $3.5$ black balls (suitably interpreted).  Again, I don't see a sensible way of working generally...these things are badly path dependent  and keeping track of all the paths is painful.

Comment: Thank you, I will try  to understand at least the calculation of P(X=3). My question will not receive the attention it deserves due to the quick downvote,

Comment: I just upvoted it to cancel that downvote out.  I'd be very interested to see if someone can spot a good way to compute this.  Bootstrapping the computation shouldn't be too bad...if we have completely solved the problem for a given $k$ then we can forget the paths that led us to a given total, and just work with the total.  But maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Can you give me ur code for k=3, i found 0.0481757 not ur result  0.047249059

Comment: Oh, I just did it in Excel, So I could see all the cases.  If you have debugged your formula, I would go with that.

Comment: To elaborate:  I simply listed all $36$ possible pairs of dice rolls and worked each case separately.  The path dependence is hard to get around.  The path $(1,6)$ is much more likely to result in termination than the path $(6,1)$. Of course, having survived either of the paths, all you care about is that $7$ extra black balls have been added (though, of course you do need to record the probability of reaching that state).

Comment: You are right $\mathbb P(X=3)=\dfrac 1{2.6^2}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^6\dfrac {k+1}{k+2}\sum_{i=1}^{6}\dfrac 1{i+k+1}= 0.0472490588115\dots$